# AWS DMS: simplified permissions for SQL Server when not replicating ongoing changes

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to set up AWS Data Migration service for a SQL Server database (on-premise) to an RDS instance.

I am only interested in existing data, not ongoing changes, since the source DB is populated by a batch process.

DMS seems convenient but has [significant prerequisites in terms of allowed access in SQL Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html) -- either `sysadmin` role, or a series of other permissions to allow access to backups and transaction logs.

Is there a simplified process in DMS (or elsewhere in AWS) that only needs sufficient access to introspect schemas and query tables on the source?